# Setting "Top Bar" to "none" in "Attributes Inspector" for iOS storyboard does nothing

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I used to do everything programmatically but have recently decided to revisit using GUIs to design views. I am using Storyboard in iOS5.

On one of my view controller, in "Attributes Inspector" I set the "Top Bar" to "none" and in storyboard, it removes the navigation bar. But, when I run the app, it still shows up. Do I have to remove it programmatically?

PS: I am using push in "segue" so it should put the view controller into the top of the stack. I am not using modal which I initially tried but gave me to much headache.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you're using a navigation controller? If that's the case, you will indeed not be able to remove the navigation bar from a specific view controller using IB; you'll have to set it's `hidden` property to `YES` in code to do it. The IB setting `Top Bar` is only for measurements&sizes AFAIK, so it won't affect the behaviour of the bar. BTW, a modal segue is for segue'ing without pushing to the stack; for navigation controllers you'll always have to use a push segue.